# r generating a column with values based on a criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns like this below

```
   w     p
   0.5   0.5267
   0.5   0.5239
   1.0   0.5267
   1.0   0.5267
   1.0   0.5267
   0.5   0.3870
   0.5   0.3566
   1.0   0.4914
   1.0   0.4914  
   0.125 0.5267 
   0.125 0.5239 
   0.125 0.3870 
   0.125 0.3844 
   0.125 0.4942 
   0.125 0.4914 
   0.125 0.3566 
   0.125 0.3540
```

I am trying to create a third column based on this criteria below

```
Step1 : Start with Row 1 and check the value in Column w. 
        Row 1 column w is not 1  
Step2 : if the value in column w is not 1, then read the next value in column w. 
        Read the next column w value (Row 2)
Step3 : repeat step 2 until the sum of values from column w is 1.
        Column w row1 and row2 , 0.5 + 0.5 = 1
Step4 : Then read the corresponding values in column p.
        0.5267,  0.5239
Step5 : Multiply the values in column p with corresponding values in column w.
        0.5267*0.5 , 0.5239*0.5
Step6 : Add the values from Step 5
        0.5267*0.5 +  0.5239*0.5 
Step6 : Divide the values in column p with sum from step5.
        0.5267/(0.5267*0.5 +  0.5239*0.5) 
        0.5239/(0.5267*0.5 +  0.5239*0.5)
```

The expected output is follows

```
   w     p        Result
   0.5   0.5267   0.5267/(0.5267*0.5 +  0.5239*0.5) 
   0.5   0.5239   0.5239/(0.5267*0.5 +  0.5239*0.5)
   1.0   0.5267   1
   1.0   0.5267   1
   1.0   0.5267   1 
   0.5   0.3870   0.3870/(0.3870*0.5 +  0.3566*0.5)
   0.5   0.3566   0.3566/(0.3870*0.5 +  0.3566*0.5)
   1.0   0.4914   1
   1.0   0.4914   1
   0.125 0.5267   0.5267/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.5239   0.5239/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.3870   0.3870/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.3844   0.3844/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.4942   0.4942/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.4914   0.4914/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.3566   0.3566/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
   0.125 0.3540   0.3540/(0.5267*0.125 + 0.5239*0.125 + 0.3870*0.125 + 0.3844*0.125 + 0.4942*0.125 + 0.4914*0.125 + 0.3566*0.125 + 0.3540*0.125)
```

I could do this using for loops ans ifelse statements, wondering if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a group using cumulative sum of `w` values and calculate the `result`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = ceiling(cumsum(w))) %>%
  mutate(result = p/sum(w * p)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr)


# A tibble: 17 x 3
#       w     p result
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 0.5   0.527  1.00 
# 2 0.5   0.524  0.997
# 3 1     0.527  1    
# 4 1     0.527  1    
# 5 1     0.527  1    
# 6 0.5   0.387  1.04 
# 7 0.5   0.357  0.959
# 8 1     0.491  1    
# 9 1     0.491  1    
#10 0.125 0.527  1.20 
#11 0.125 0.524  1.19 
#12 0.125 0.387  0.880
#13 0.125 0.384  0.874
#14 0.125 0.494  1.12 
#15 0.125 0.491  1.12 
#16 0.125 0.357  0.811
#17 0.125 0.354  0.805
```

---

This can be done in `data.table` as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := p/sum(w * p), ceiling(cumsum(w))]
```